# akka-http how to send response as html

Tags: akka-http

http for processing my routes is there any way i can pass html as response to the get request

```
path("employees" / "confirm" / Segments(1)) { confirmationCode =>       
  get {
    complete {
        UserBo().confirmEmail(confirmationCode(0)).map[ToResponseMarshallable]{
          case Right(message) => (OK,ContentTypes.`text/html(UTF-8)`,message.toString)
          case Left(e) => Left(e)
        }
    }
  }
}
```

im getting a jason response for this code is there any way i can get html as response

Comment: im using akka-http for processing my routes

Comment: What version of akka-http are you using?  I don't see an implicit that will turn a tuple of `(StatusCode, ContentType, String)` into a `ToResponseMarshallable`.